# How to resolve a stack overflow error while solving the coin change problem using recursion

Tags: scala

I'm getting stack overflow error while running the below function for coin change problem.

```
    {

      def countchanger(m: Int, c:List[Int]): Int = {

        if (money == 0 || coins.isEmpty) 1
        else if (money < 0) 0
        else countchanger(money - coins.head, coins) + countchanger(money, coins.tail)
      }
      countchanger(money, coins.sorted)
}
```

Appreciate any help in understanding why the stack overflow error and how this function can be written in a better way.

This is not an issue when countchanger function is removed from countChange function.

```
def countChange(money: Int, coins: List[Int]): Int =
    {

      if ((money < 0) || coins.isEmpty) 0
      else if (money == 0) 1
      else countChange(money - coins.head, coins) + countChange(money, coins.tail)

    }
```

Comment: Somehow I doubt you did the exercise on your own. But anyway. The problem in your original code block is that you call coins.head and coins.tail in countchanger instead of c.head and c.tail. The inner function here is unnecessary anyway. Also, your formatting is strange, and you only presented part of your original function, not all of it. This makes it hard to help you.

Comment: @user6337 Now I see this was a fundamental parameter issue where in the money and coin should have been replaced by m and c. But I oversaw that due to the stackover flow error and thought this problem can only be solved by tail recursion. Thanks

Comment: If you are taking the course on Coursera, I would recommend listening carefully to the lectures and doing the problems yourself. You will learn more that way.

Comment: In other words, don't peek at the answers.

Comment: I have a feeling that the course is too difficult for you. If that is true, you should switch to another one where you can do the homework by yourself. You can ask for help, but you shouldn't be looking at the answers before solving the problem. You will learn nothing and only waste your time that way. If it is still your first week taking the course, you can still drop it for a full refund. Take a look at the course "Python for Everybody" from the University of Michigan. You can always come back to Scala later, when you are ready.

Comment: @user6337 thanks for the recommendation. I understand that this was a silly question and I should have atleast done a debug before approaching the experts.  You are right this course is difficult for me. I have scripting experience with python and has coded in cpp but that may not make me smart enough to understand the tougher algorithms and functional programming concepts. Thanks again for the expert help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you have called coins.tail and coins.head rather than c.tail and c.head. This means that the function is endlessly calling itself from the second iteration onward with the same input parameters, thus never completing and hitting the maximum depth of recursive calls allowed. A good example of why maintaining the scope of variable names is important!